# Maya - animation curves for selected objects using python

Tags: python, animation, maya

As the title says, I am trying to get all animation curves from selected objects(transforms) using python in maya.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`listConnections`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/listConnections.html) command, which by default acts on selected objects. The `t='animCurve'` ensures that you're only returned animation curves.

```
cmds.listConnections(t='animCurve')
```

This returns a list of animation curves driving your selection.

Comment: You can also specify an object directly with `cmds.listConnections("object_name_here", t="animCurve")`.  You can also limit to a particular channel, for example `cmds.listConnections, ("object_name.translateX", t="animCurve")`

Comment: Want to add that nearly all Maya commands work on selections, either the user selection or a arbitrary list you provide in the command.

Comment: Additional notes: This completely fails if there are any utility nodes in between the curve and object. In fact, you risk getting anim curves that drive channels from different objects.